# Best Mysql Table & Engine design for Logging users' data (ip, useragent, date, referral value etc)

Tags: mysql, logging, archive, myisam

Currently my logs table is huge and thus all inserts are slow. My table collects the following users' info, and store it at run time: IP, Useragent string, referral data, date, host value etc.

Current engine is: MyIsam

This table is rarely used to retrieve info and simply collects data.

The ID column is set as the Primary Key and is Auto Incremented.

I would like to make things faster since Insert is probably takes too long (I got like hundreds of inserts per minute).

Please suggest what would be the best table structure for such Table that logs users data every second.

I already have a number of solutions to try, such as using the Archive engine, but should I play with the index value too? I don't know.

Comment: If speed is important, don't log directly to a database table. Log to a CSV file and periodically batch update your table with `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: but, would not logging to a CSV file make the server slower too ? cause I will be like direct logging to a csv file

Comment: Appending a row of data to a CSV file is much, much faster than performing a database query. Similarly, performing a periodic batch update of hundreds of rows from a CSV file is much faster than performing hundreds of individual queries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about the Table engine, should I go for Archive, or stay with MyIsam?

Comment: InnoDB. MyIsam is not acid compliant, and not suitable for heavy writing

Comment: Archive is intended for storage of unindexed data, which probably suits your logging application quite well. It will make retrieval (when you need it) very much slower. This might not be a problem for you. I think you'd need to see what the effect of each is, and maybe consider using MyISAM or InnoDB for current logging data, and transfer it to an Archive format table once the data is no longer current - maybe after a week, or a month.

Comment: Great, I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: @Mike W (or others), when appending a new entry / row to the .csv file, should I use several .csv files, or keep using the same one for the appending of each row? Bear in mind that my app will likely to append hundreds of rows each minute. thanks

Comment: I think you'd have to try some of these things for yourself. More files means more management. Fewer files means you might want to update your tables more frequently. Which works best depends on your app and your supporting hardware. There's no one right answer.